# Put user profile photo to map pin in ios dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, ios7

I want to show all user photos to map in **iOS**.Here,all user photos are coming from server through web service.

let me attach screen show what I want to achieve to get better idea.[image]

e.g image of pin:
[image]

So I want to create custom pin like above for all users to show in map of iphone application.

can any one redirect me to achieve above task in ios.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pasting a code from one of my project. but you will get main idea. i am dealing with bunch or different stores so i add tag on every annotation. also i am using SDWebImage library to load remote images dynamically.
the green pin is mapPin and circle image is dynamically loaded from server

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation {

            if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
            return nil;

        MKAnnotationView *aView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"mapPin"];
        if(aView){
            aView.annotation = annotation;
        } else {

            aView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"mapPin"];
            ESMapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation=(ESMapViewAnnotation *)annotation;
            ZBStore *s=(ZBStore *)[dataArray objectAtIndex:newAnnotation.tag];
            NSString *iURL=s.Icon;
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iURL]
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Question.jpg"]];
            imageView.layer.borderWidth=1;
            imageView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
            imageView.backgroundColor=s.BColor;
            CGRect f= CGRectMake(2,2,46,43);
            [imageView setFrame:f];
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius=22.0;
            imageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
            aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

            [aView addSubview:imageView];
            aView.enabled = YES;
            aView.canShowCallout = YES;
            aView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gPin2.png"];//here we use a nice image instead of the default pins


    }
    return aView;
    //return nil;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that this code is setting the image only when an annotation view is _created_ (alloc+init) for some annotation X.  If that view is then _re-used_ (if dequeue returns a previously-created view) for some other annotation Y, then annotation Y will show the image for annotation X.

Comment: Thanks, but now not able to click on pin point...for open call out...please suggest.